# Input field is clearing text when I'm telling it not to 

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, haml, sunspot

I have an input field that was written with `onfocus="this.value=''` , but recently decided to change it to `onfocus="this.select()` . The trouble is that when I went to change it, it still clears! I searched my entire javascript library, html, everything looking for what could be causing that. Nothing is being called of the likes.

I tried clearing my cache. And I tried searching for `value=''` and `cl(`

Anyone know how I could debug this? Or at worse, override what it's doing to make it do what I want?

My code :

```
<input type="text" value="Enter Keyword or Co. Name" name="q" id="q" class="foobar">
```

I have also tried :

```
<input type="text" value="Enter Keyword or Co. Name" name="q" id="q" class="foobar" onfocus="this.select();">
```

Thanks!

Comment: @trip did u tested in various browsers ? Are the results same ?

Comment: Yah. I spotted that answer you put up for a second, and have been playing around with it. Trying to make jQuery intercept the call somehow. :D maybe a little preventDefault() or return false. But it's too quick!

Comment: Could you post the function that you are passing to select()?

Comment: Yeah, it'd help to see more of the code.

Comment: Well at least, I'm not the only person dumbfounded.

Comment: We aren't dumbfounded. The code that I posted works perfectly in jsfiddle. Your problem persists only because you have yet to 1) properly explain the effect you're trying to accomplish (I can only assume selecting all text when a user clicks in a text form field) and 2) you have yet to post the rest of your code or the link to the full source.

Comment: @Moses, Its a proprietary code I can't expose, and over a gig of it at that. As far as js goes, there's nothing in any of it that could signify it doing that. And yes, I know your versions work. They do for me too outside of my environment. Something else is prohibiting it from occuring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $(function() { 
  $('input[type=text]').focus(function() {
     $(this).trigger('select');
  });
});
```

You can test it [**here**](http://jsbin.com/uroli3)

Comment: Thanks Avinash. This does work, I know. But something else is rendering the clear(), or value="". And it's called before jQuery or javascript, or even onfocus="" is called.

Answer (score 0):

Have you viewed the source and verified that your page is actually using the changed code?  Sometimes I have to clear my cached version before it will pull changes.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/mzFQk/1/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="Enter Keyword or Co. Name" name="q" id="q" class="foobar" />
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#q').click(function(evt) {
   evt.preventDefault();
   this.select();
}); // make sure to attach this script to the domReady event
```

This code works perfectly, if you cannot get this to work in your website, then we cannot help you until you post the source code.

Comment: Yah, tried clearing the cache. Searched for things like `cl(this)`, and `value=''`

Comment: `First, I would clear your cache ` lol, How are you going to clear his cache =)

Comment: I bet he can split the red sea as well

Comment: I tried that. It clears it before the jQuery kicks in. Even tried `preventDefault();` and `return false;`

Comment: GREAT SITE, jsfiddle. :D Thanks for the recommends.

Answer (score 0):

You're all going to hate me, but I found it. At the very end of the day, I just search for `"#q"`, and found it.

```
$("#q").focus(function() {
   $("this").val() == ""
});
```

I deleted it with my battle ax.